# Sort folders according last modified date of subfolders

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I have a windows network share with over 1000 folders that also have subfolders.

I want to delete the folders that have not been modified since a few years.

When I sort in File Explorer after "date modified", it sorts the parent folders correctly.

But changes in subfolders are not considered.

I try to create a PowerShell script that sorts all folders on the network share considering the last write time in folder or subfolder.

Unfortunately in the current state it lists only the latest modified folder over and over again.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\tmp -Directory | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | Select {$_.FullName}, {$_.LastWriteTime} -First 1 }
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want "the most recent LastWriteTime of any sub-file/folder", which is

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
```

Then you could write the whole thing like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\test' -Directory | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, @{Label='LastWriteInside'; Expression={ 
        ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force|
         Sort-object -property LastWriteTime|
         Select-Object -expandproperty lastwritetime -Last 1)
        }} |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteInside
```